# How to Subtract annoted values in django?

Tags: django, django-views

I am unable to subtract annotated values of two different queries in django views.

I tried this:

```
    qs = Stockdata.objects.filter(User=self.request.user, Company=company_details.pk, Date__gte=selectdatefield_details.Start_Date, Date__lte=selectdatefield_details.End_Date)
    total = qs.annotate(the_sum=Coalesce(Sum('salestock__Quantity'),0)).values('the_sum')
    total2 = qs.annotate(the_sum2=Coalesce(Sum('purchasestock__Quantity_p'),0)).values('the_sum2')
    totalqty = total2 - total
```

I tried using Coalesce from django.db.models.function but getting this error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'QuerySet' and 'QuerySet'
```

Is there any function in django to subtract values?

Do anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong in my code?

Comment: Could you please post your models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
qs = qs.annotate(
    sales_sum = Coalesce(Sum('salestock__Quantity'),0),
    purchase_sum = Coalesce(Sum('purchasestock__Quantity_p'),0)
)
qs = qs.annotate(
    difference = ExpressionWrapper(F('sales_sum') - F('purchase_sum'), output_field=DecimalField())
)
```

Comment: It is throwing me this error now 'TypeError: annotate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' ' ...How to fix this?

Comment: Sorry, it's `qs.annotate`, not `queryset.annotate`. Corrected it.

Comment: But its not returning any values its coming out like this "<QuerySet [<Stockdata: Iphone>, <Stockdata: Samsung Galaxy>]>"... "Iphone" and "Samsung Galaxy" are some entries I have put in my Stockdata model...

Comment: Check the output of `print(qs.values())` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [aggregate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
total = qs.aggregate(the_sum=Coalesce(Sum('salestock__Quantity'),0))
total2 = qs.aggregate(the_sum2=Coalesce(Sum('purchasestock__Quantity_p'),0))

totalqty = total2['the_sum2'] - total['the_sum']
```

Comment: I want to find the total quantity for each stock instance but aggregate will give me the value of total quantity for all stock...